# What is gravitational force between two objects

Tags: newtonian-gravity

What is the gravitational force between two objects?

Comment: Your edit (removing the last two sentences) makes the question too vague to answer, and it also makes the existing answer a bit confusing. I'd encourage you to either revert to your original version or (if you meant to ask something different) elaborate on what you really want to know.

Answer (score 1):

It's the latter (force of one on the other). [Newton's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) guarantees that if you add up all of the forces within any collection of objects then the sum will be zero.

Newton's law of gravition states that if you have two point-like bodies with masses $m$ and $M$ separated by a distance $r$ then the magnitude of the force each exerts on the other is given by:
$$|F| = G \frac{mM}{r^2}.$$
The direction of force will always be along the line connecting the two bodies and toward the center of that line (i.e. it pulls them together).